# Android Design Support Library: [Q] 2 Subtitle in extended Toolbar

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-toolbar, subtitle, androiddesignsupport

I want to add two subtitle in extended `ToolBar`. I tried adding two **textviews**, but my app title is going away because of **padding** attribute of `TextView`. I want to design following type of extended `ToolBar`.

[image: 2 Subtitle req]

layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/tabanim_maincontent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabanim_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tabanim_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:titleMarginTop="14dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/tabanim_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: can you post a screenshot of what it looks like right now?

Comment: @adao7000, screenshot with textviews ? I've added the screenshot  without textviews and the way I want to achieve.

Comment: Yes, show me a screenshot of what you have tried already

Comment: I used following code for 2 textview in my layout file inside toolbar tag 
            `<TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Toolbar SubTitle1"
                android:paddingTop="110dp"

                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />`
' 
Here is the screenshot : [link](http://i.imgur.com/mVETs1Y.png)

Comment: @Chris Banes, Sir can you help me ?